# How to safely apply multiple axon event

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I am creating an application for learning purpose and in the application i am trying to raise multiple events  i want to know is it safe trigger/apply multiple events one after another
e.g. in my demo application  when user(lender) deposit loan cash i want to first deposit the amount to lender account and then withdraws from borrower account.  Below is the code i wrote

```
@CommandHandler
public void handle(LoanCashDepositCommand command) {
    LoanCashDepositedEvent event = LoanCashDepositedEvent.builder()
            .id(command.getId())
            .amount(command.getAmount())                                                    
            .build();

    AggregateLifecycle.apply(event);
}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(LoanCashDepositedEvent event){
    if(event.getAmount() > this.amount ) {
        FundsDepositedEvent fundsDepositedEvent = FundsDepositedEvent.builder()
                .id(this.lenderId)
                .amount(this.amount) 
                .build();

        AggregateLifecycle.apply(fundsDepositedEvent);

        FundsWithdrawnEvent fundsWithdrawnEvent = FundsWithdrawnEvent.builder()
                .id(this.borrowerId)
                .amount(event.getAmount() -  this.amount)    
                .build();

        AggregateLifecycle.apply(fundsWithdrawnEvent);

        AggregateLifecycle.markDeleted();   
    }
    else{

        FundsDepositedEvent fundsDepositedEvent = FundsDepositedEvent.builder()
                .id(this.lenderId)
                .amount(event.getAmount())
                .build();

        AggregateLifecycle.apply(fundsDepositedEvent);

        FundsWithdrawnEvent fundsWithdrawnEvent = FundsWithdrawnEvent.builder()
                .id(this.borrowerId)
                .amount(event.getAmount())
                .build();

        AggregateLifecycle.apply(fundsWithdrawnEvent);

        this.amount -= event.getAmount();
        
        if(this.amount == 0) {
            AggregateLifecycle.markDeleted();
        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with applying multiple events inside the same `@CommandHandler`. In fact, that is quite normal I would say.

But, for your example/use case, it does not seems to be a simple `apply` but rather a [Saga](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/sagas) where you have to manage 2 different `Aggregates` (`Account` in your case) getting money from one and sending to another inside the same (distributed) transaction.
Also from your example, you should not `apply` inside an `@EventSourcingHandler` method but on the `@CommandHandler` as I said before.

If you need more help, I would recommend a small sample where we can see what you are trying to do and where you are having a hard time.

---

Edit 1: Here is a link for a hands-on Saga blogpost that can help you on this journey!
https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/sagas-in-practice

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback , i  already have a sample will tweak it and make my GitHub repository public. After studying saga i think its the way to go with these type of scenarios

Comment: Glad to help! If you want to have a look at Saga with Axon, I can recommend this blog as a source for you: https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/sagas-in-practice